# Node.js dev environment in Docker on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, docker

I have tried everything I can think of. I have read the docs, blogs and tried following samples on github.

But I can't seem to get it to work.

What I want to do is simple. I want to write my node.js code on my windows 8.1 machine, and I also want to run the code from within a Docker container without having to rebuild the container all the time. So I want to map a directory on my Windows Host to a directory inside the container.

I have created this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:0.10.38

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

ENV ZMQ_VERSION 4.1.3
ENV LIBSODIUM_VERSION 1.0.3

RUN curl -SLO "https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && rm libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN curl -SLO "http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && rm zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN ldconfig

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 35729

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have this simple server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var zmq = require('zmq');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('ZMQ: ' + zmq.version);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

And this simple package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker-node-hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "zmq": "^2.14.0"
  }
}
```

I have installed the latest Docker Toolbox, and can run the Docker Hello World example fine. I try to build my docker image like this when I am in the directory where my Dockerfile is.

`docker build -t dockernodetest:dockerfile .`

I then try to run it, also from the same location inside the Docker Quickstart Terminal. I use the hash since the tag doesn't take for some reason:

`docker run -v //c/Bitbucket/docker-node-hello-world/:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 -i -t 9cfd34e046a5 ls ./usr/src/app`

The result of this is an empty directory. I was hoping I could just invoke

`docker run -v //c/Bitbucket/docker-node-hello-world/:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 -i -t 9cfd34e046a5 npm start`

But since the host directory isn't available it fails. I have the feeling that I have misunderstood something very basic. I just don't know what.

Comment: You might want to take a read through [Working with containers](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/usingdocker/) to help you understand what's happened after each step.

So what is the output when running a `docker images` command?

Comment: Also what is the content of `entrypoint.sh` as `ENTRYPOINT` is defined, arguments will be passed to that script - see [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Answer (score 4):

First let's start from the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:0.10.38-onbuild

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

ENV ZMQ_VERSION 4.1.3
ENV LIBSODIUM_VERSION 1.0.3

RUN curl -SLO "https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && rm libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN curl -SLO "http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && rm zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN ldconfig

EXPOSE 3000 35729
```

From line 1 I've used the `0.10.38-onbuild` tag because I want to take advantage of [onbuild scripts](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/0.10/onbuild/Dockerfile) that will run to create the `/usr/src/app` directory and run `npm install`

Then `server.js` and `package.json` are as you have written them. These are both in the same working directory as the `Dockerfile` as well.

Next we build the image

```
docker build -t dockernodetest .
```

I've omitted the `dockerfile` tag as it seemed unnecessary. The client will automatically add a `latest` tag anyway. To see what images you've have locally run `docker images`.

At this point we should have an image ready to run but let us first check that the files we wanted to load are then and that `npm install` created the `node_modules` directory

```
$ docker run dockernodetest ls /usr/src/app
Dockerfile
node_modules
package.json
server.js
```

We're ready at this point to run our little nodejs app

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:3000 dockernodetest

> docker-node-hello-world@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js

Example app listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

In this instance I've used the `-p 8080:3000` flag to map the container's 3000 port to port 8080 on my host machine. Note that I didn't have any other commands at the end because the `-onbuild` image I've pulled form has a `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` and so the default action is to run the `start` package script.

So to make the development cycle even faster you want to mount your working directory to the container via the `-v` option

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:3000 -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app dockernodetest

> docker-node-hello-world@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

npm ERR! Linux 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! docker-node-hello-world@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
```

But what's happened here? Because we mounted the current working directory it overwrote what was previously there in `/usr/src/app` including our `node_modules` directory.

So the quick fix here is to now run a `npm install` in our current working directory and rerun the `docker run` command.

```
$ npm install
docker-node-hello-world@1.0.0 /home/ec2-user/dockernode
└─┬ express@4.13.3
  ├─┬ accepts@1.2.13
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.7
...
$ docker run -it -p 8080:3000 -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app dockernodetest

> docker-node-hello-world@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js

Example app listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Now if you make an update to your `server.js` file just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and restart you docker image though you might want to use something like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to make this even more seamless.

Comment: Wow, thank you @jeedo. Very thorough answer. Can't wait to try it out tonite. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer. It definitely led me on the right path. It took me longer than I had thought, but I got it working.

There were a few things that didn't work, but I got it working at last. Here is a rundown of what I went through.

1. I wasn't able to use the onbuild scripts as you suggested. The reason being that when I base my image on the onbuild script it runs `npm install` before I install ZeroMQ.
2. Running `npm install` outside my docker image wasn't an option either as you suggested for when I mapped a drive. One of the reasons I want to run this in Docker is that I want an environment where all dependencies (such as ZeroMQ) are installed and available. This is something that on some environments is difficult, and I want to run this on both windows and linux hosts.
3. I really want to use `nodemon` for when I develop so I also had to install this globally in the image, and also invoke nodemon when starting the container. So I had to extend your example as you suggested.
4. I had a lot of trouble getting the mapped volumes to work. It turns out that on a windows host you have to be in the context of `C:\users\<username>` to be able to map volumes on the host from the container. Once I figured that out and undid all the weird experiments I had been through to make it all work, I got that to work. Using `"$PWD"` as you suggested when invoking `docker run` is also weird on a windows host. You have to prefix with a forward slash like this: `/"$PWD"`.
5. When I figured it all out I started looking at docker compose, partly because I didn't want to keep typing out the long docker run commands (that I kept getting wrong) but also because in my real projects I want multiple containers for my database and other services I need.

So this is what it looks like now. It works exactly the way I want it to work. I now have a container where all dependencies are installed inside the container and whenever I run my container it first invokes `npm install` and the `nodemon server.js`. All files including the installed npm modules are on the host but mapped inside the container where everything is run from.

File 1 - docker-compose.yml (notice I don't need the $PWD variable, but can just use a `.` relative path for the host path)

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ".:/usr/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

File 2 - Dockerfile

```
FROM node:0.10.40

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir /usr/src/node_modules

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

ENV ZMQ_VERSION 4.1.3
ENV LIBSODIUM_VERSION 1.0.3

RUN curl -SLO "https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION \
    && rm libsodium-$LIBSODIUM_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN curl -SLO "http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar xvf zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION \
    && rm zeromq-$ZMQ_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN ldconfig

RUN npm install -g nodemon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD export NODE_PATH=/usr/src/node_modules && cp package.json /usr/src && npm install --prefix /usr/src && npm start

EXPOSE 3000 35729
```

File 3 - package.json (notice I use the `-L` flag when invoking nodemon. This is needed when running inside a container)

```
{
  "name": "docker-node-hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node hello world",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L server.js"
  },
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "zmq": "^2.14.0"
  }
}
```

File 4 - server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var zmq = require('zmq');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('ZMQ Version: ' + zmq.version);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

To build use the following command

```
docker-compose build
```

To run use the following command

```
docker-compose up
```

At this time I can develop my app on my host, and whenever I change a file my node server is restarted. When I add a new dependency to my package.json I have to restart my container to run `npm install`.

The only thing I don't have working yet is how I make rebuilding my image a smooth operation. What happens is that after I build a new image I have to delete my old container before I can run a new container. The mapping is locked by the old container.

I would really like to give you the credit @jeedo. I would not have reached this solution without your help. I don't know how to do that and also mark this as the solution.

Edit: I just edited this to add something to my Dockerfile. I moved the node_modules folder away from the host filesystem. I had some trouble with paths becoming too long on Windows. These changes make sure the node_modules are always installed inside the container.